# ElementaryOS / Specific layout

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, elementary-os

For switching layouts between three different languages I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> but this approach very slowly.

I want to use specific combination for the specific layout. Like:

- English -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
- Ukraine -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
- Spain -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

How to do it on ElementaryOS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to do with commands. The commands for making those changes are, respectively, `setxkbmap us`, `setxkbmap fr` and `setxkbmap es`.

I don't have experience with elementaryOS. If elementaryOS has a built-in keyboard shortcut manager that lets you define custom keybindings, assign keybindings to those commands using that.

If it doesn't have a keyboard shortcut manager, you can get one with elementary-tweaks, according to http://elementary.io/answers/keyboard-shortcuts. That source is two years old, so I don't know if it still applies - perhaps elementaryOS has a good keyboard shortcut manager by default now.